# Searching value in list of list then appending to empty list

Tags: python, list

I have come across this:

```
finalList = []
dateTime = "SCHEDULE: " + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H%M")) + "H"

for sublist in main_List:
    if dateTime in sublist[0]:
        finalList.append(sublist)
```

Here's the value of `main_List` it is a list that has a value of lists,

```
[['SCHEDULE: 1509H', 'SCHEDULE: 1404H', 'ST: 1500', 'PING: www.google.com'], ['SCHEDULE: 1509H', 'SCHEDULE: 1700H', 'SCHEDULE: 2001H', 'SCHEDULE: 1817H', 'ST: 1169', 'FA']]
```

My problem is, how can I get the value of the `SCHEDULE` equals the `dateTime` in every list.

I think in this part of my code is wrong `sublist[0]` because it's only getting the first index of the list. How can I search the values in `sublist`?

Comment: You answered your question yourself. You're only searching for this string _in another string_, which is `sublist[0]`, but you should search _in the whole sublist_, and you know how to do that.

Comment: @ForceBru is it something like this sir, `sublist`? but I tried this one, it gives me the whole value of sublist.

Comment: Yeah, you check `if your_string in sublist:` and then append the sublist as you do in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems right here:

1. `dateTime = "SCHEDULE: " + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H%M")` this will return something like `'SCHEDULE: 1119'` which will be missing the trailing `H`, not matching the format from your lists.
2. You should be iterating like this:

```
for sublist in main_list:
    if dateTime in sublist:
         finalList.append(sublist)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering sir, but how can I only get the specific value that much to the dateTime? e.g. `SCHEDULE : 1509H` only this one, because in your script I getting the whole value of list that much the `dateTime`.

Comment: If dateTime is in sublist then you can get it's index using `.index()` on `sublist` and only append that element to the finalList.

Comment: I did it like this `finalList.append(sublist.index(dateTime))`, but it gives me the number of the index. How can I get the exact value, sir?

Comment: `finalList.append(sublist[sublist.index(dateTime)])`

Answer (score 3):

You need to change **shedule_date_time** format as your sublist contains trailing **H** in it.

```
main_list = [['SCHEDULE: 1509H', 'SCHEDULE: 1404H', 'ST: 1500', 'PING: www.google.com'], ['SCHEDULE: 1509H', 'SCHEDULE: 1700H', 'SCHEDULE: 2001H', 'SCHEDULE: 1817H', 'ST: 1169', 'FA']]


# adding extra "H" to match with your main_list data
shedule_date_time = "SCHEDULE: " + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H%MH")) 

finalList = [sublist for sublist in main_list if shedule_date_time in sublist]
```